# approximation in $C^{2,\alpha}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Fix $\alpha,\delta\in(0,1).$ Suppose $f\in C(\mathbb{S}^{n-1})$ is a continious function such that $\|f-1\|_{\sup}\leq \delta/2$. Is it possible to find $f_i\in C^{2,\alpha}(\mathbb{S}^{n-1})$ such that $\|f_i-1\|_{C^{2,\alpha}}\leq \delta$
and $\|f_i-f\|_{\sup}\to 0$ as $i\to \infty.$ Here $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ denotes the unit sphere of $\mathbb{R}^n.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\|f_i - 1\|_{C^{2,\alpha}} \le \delta$ for all $i$, then for all $0<\beta<\alpha$, by passing to a subsequence if necessary, $f_i-1 \to g$ in $C^{2,\beta}$. As $f_i \to f$ in $C^0$, this mean $f = g+1$ is a $C^{2,\beta}$ function. Thus such a sequence cannot be found if for example $f$ is not $C^2$.

Comment: So if $f$ is $C^2$, then it is possible to find such $f_i?$

Comment: $f$ has to be $C^{2, \beta}$ for all $\beta <\alpha$. I am not sure if this is the same as saying that $f$ has to be $C^{2, \alpha}$. @happy